# How to make PHP array value equal to each other faster

Tags: php, arrays, loops

let say I have an array of this values:

```
$arr = array(190, 2215, 2, 61);
```

after I run my code with 694 loops, I got this final values:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 696
    [1] => 696
    [2] => 696
    [3] => 696
)
```

how can I make the process faster and much better?? I only can increase or decrease the value by 1

Below are my codes.

```
<?php 
    echo '<pre>';
    $arr = array(190, 2215, 2, 61);
    sort($arr);
    print_r($arr);

    $arrLength = count($arr);
    $counter = 0;

    loop:
    $counter++;

    for($i=0; $i<$arrLength; $i++){
        if($arr[$i] < $arr[$arrLength-1] && $arr[$arrLength-1] != $arr[$arrLength-2]) {
            $arr[$i]++;
            $arr[$arrLength-1]--;
        }else if($arr[$i] < $arr[$arrLength-1] && $arr[$arrLength-1] == $arr[$arrLength-2]) {
            $arr[$i]++;
        }
     }

    if($arr[0] != $arr[$arrLength-1]) goto loop;

    print_r($arr);
    print_r($counter);
?>
```

Comment: Sounds like [tag:homework].  Is it?  If so, you'll get more useful answers if you tag it as such.

Comment: Seeing a `goto` instead of a very obvious `do...while` statement makes me very afraid to ask: What in the world are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Kolink: Performance, duh, everybody knows `goto` gets so much more done in so little time :P

Comment: @BoltClock thanks :) I need to achieve worst case performance by O(n2)

Comment: What do you mean you can only increase or decrease the value by 1? It would take 1521 iterations to get 2215 to 696 so you obviously decrease it by more then 1 per iteration...

Comment: have you considered using array_map function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code just finds a weighted average between the two largest values in an array, and then sets everything to it (Second largest element has weight of the `number of elements - 1`, the largest element has weight 1). You can do this much more easily and faster like this:

```
<?php 
    echo '<pre>';
    $arr = array(190, 2215, 2, 61);
    sort($arr);
    print_r($arr);

    $arrLength = count($arr);

    // Find weighted average of second largest element and largest element in array:
    $avg = floor(($arr[$arrLength - 2] * ($arrLength - 1) + $arr[$arrLength - 1])/$arrLength);

    // Only need this line if you need the end value of counter from your code
    // $counter = $avg - $arr[0]; // (964 in this example)
    $arr = array_fill(0, $arrLength, $avg);

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

Note: if all you need is the number (696) then you don't need the `array_fill` line. Just use the `$avg` variable for whatever you need it for later.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. thanks for the code but how about I really need to increase or decrease each of the array value by 1 to get the number (696) ?

Comment: @skycrew I'm not sure what you mean. If you can only decrease or increase by 1 then use a loop. But this way you can end up with the same result with no loop. If you need to know how many iterations your code would've made then uncomment the `$counter = $avg - $arr[0];` line. Then you can add `print_r($counter);` to the end to get the exact same output as your code above with no loop.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. in that case I accept your answer :) but I still can vote it. heh anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: @skycrew And if you're really restricted to adding and subtracting 1 for some reason, then you can change `$i<$arrLength;` to `$i < $arrLength - 1;` to shorten the number of iterations in that for loop by one.